# Calculating MSE between two images by two loops

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, mse

I was trying to derive a function calculating the MSE by the equation:

[image]

```
MSE_value1 = 0

for y in range(iH):
    for x in range(iW):
        MSE_value1 += ((image_1[y][x] - image_2[y][x]) ** 2) / (iH * iW)
```

However, after searching I saw the most general way to derive the MSE is:

```
MSE_value2 = np.mean((image_1 - image_2) ** 2)
```

I think for the algorithm they are the same, but the values turn out to be 34.6803 and 79.4176 at last after calculating the MSE between these two test images. (Left is the original image, and right is a denoised one.)

[image]
[image]

Is there something wrong in the first block of code (to calculate the MSE_value1)?

Comment: to avoid the overflow which generates this weird behavior, you can change the images type from `uint8` to `int`, so you can have consistent results: `image_x = image_x.astype(int)`.

Comment: Thank you @bilai. I didn't notice that! However, it got smaller to 5.6178, smaller than before.

Comment: ` import cv2
import numpy as np
image_1  = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)
image_1 = image_1.astype(int)
image_2  = cv2.imread('2.png', 0)
image_2 = image_2.astype(int)
iH, iW = image_1.shape
MSE_value1 = 0.0
for y in range(iH):
    for x in range(iW):
        MSE_value1 += ((image_1[y][x] - image_2[y][x] )** 2) / (iH * iW)
MSE_value2 = np.mean((image_1  - image_2 ) ** 2)
print(MSE_value1, MSE_value2)` I'm getting 644.46 in both cases! please share a reproducible code to compare your results!

Comment: Thank you so much, @Bilal ! It seems that I load the file without adding `".astype(int)"` to make it as integer instead of uint8 in the image file. But why is it needed?